# Docker build image not including gltf files

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, azure-aks

I'm trying to run my website in an Azure Kubernetes Service and need to build the image using docker, however i'm getting 404 not found when trying to fetch the gltf model from the assets folder, fonts and images are working fine. This has something to do with Docker not building with the model file, as when building the image locally and running the docker image the model is still 404 not found but running it through Rider for example it works fine.
Does Docker automatically ignore these files and should I go down the path of storing my gltf files in azure storage explorer? Or am I missing something?
Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

# Install Node.js
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y \
        nodejs \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TheResistanceOnline.Web/TheResistanceOnline.Web.csproj", "TheResistanceOnline.Web/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TheResistanceOnline.Web/TheResistanceOnline.Web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TheResistanceOnline.Web"
RUN dotnet build "TheResistanceOnline.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TheResistanceOnline.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TheResistanceOnline.Web.dll"]
```

For example this when running the docker image :
[Image of Error 404 not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/va2Nk.jpg)

and this is when running from Rider

[Image of it working when running with Rider/Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZR1L.png)

When I run ng build the dist folder will contain the model file, so it must have something to do with Docker?
[Image of dist folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcc7f.png)

Comment: What are "gltf files"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF used in Three.js

Comment: @Max I've updated the post with images so its a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Apologies it was not an issue with docker, was a problem with serving static files in my Program.cs file
Heres the solution incase anyone else stumbles upon this and needs help:

```
builder.Services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ContentTypeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider
    {
        Mappings =
        {
            [".gltf"] = "model/gltf+json",
            [".glb"] = "model/gltf-binary",
            [".bin"] = "application/octet-stream"
        }
    };
});
```